# Func inside func parameter

Tags: swift, function, parameters

I was researching swift extensions when I found this

```
extension Int {
    func repetitions(task: () -> Void) {
        for _ in 0..<self {
            task()
        }
    }
}
```

I saw that there was a function inside the function parameter with a return value and I scrolled down and the result was this

```
3.repetitions {
    print("Hello!")
}
// Hello!
// Hello!
// Hello!
```

I tried finding out how this worked but I had no luck could someone explain how this works thanks.

Comment: You can learn about [closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) here. In general, I strongly recommend going over the entire language fundamentals - this investment will pay of in the long term

Comment: This is syntactic sugar called *trailing closure syntax*.  The example is the same as caling `3.repetitions(task: { print("Hello!") })`.  The closure is passed to `repetitions` which calls it `self` times where `self` is the `Int` value that the method is invoked from.